# Not reloading imageview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an 20 buttons that each an every button clicked load that array image with respect to their tag value. my problem is that only display first button image why this happning i tried this below code.

```
    images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


        [images insertObject:@"circle.png" atIndex:0];
        [images insertObject:@"cone.png" atIndex:1];
        [images insertObject:@"cube.png" atIndex:2];
        [images insertObject:@"cuboid.png" atIndex:3];
        [images insertObject:@"cylinder.png" atIndex:4];
        [images insertObject:@"ecplise.png" atIndex:5];
        [images insertObject:@"ellipsoid.png" atIndex:6];
        [images insertObject:@"frustrum of cone.png" atIndex:7];
        [images insertObject:@"kite.png" atIndex:8];
        [images insertObject:@"parallelepiped.png" atIndex:9];
        [images insertObject:@"parallelogram.png" atIndex:10];
        [images insertObject:@"polygon.png" atIndex:11];
        [images insertObject:@"rectangle.png" atIndex:12];
        [images insertObject:@"rectangula prizm.png" atIndex:13];
        [images insertObject:@"rhoumbus.png" atIndex:14];
        [images insertObject:@"sector.png" atIndex:15];
        [images insertObject:@"sphere.png" atIndex:16];
        [images insertObject:@"square.png" atIndex:17];
        [images insertObject:@"tapezoid.png" atIndex:18];
        [images insertObject:@"tourus.png" atIndex:19];
        [images insertObject:@"traingle.png" atIndex:20];


NSString * str=value2;


    NSLog(@"%@",str);

    //AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];




    NSInteger myInt = [str intValue];


    NSString *  imagename=[images objectAtIndex:myInt];

    NSLog(@"%@",imagename);


    self.imgview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    [imgview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagename]];

    [imgview setNeedsDisplay];

    [imgview reloadInputViews];
```

str contains tag value of buttons get all values properly.but only first image displayed.

Comment: first image is being visible through this code or you have a default image in XIB ?

Comment: no i am adding all that images through code......

Comment: if this imageview is in XIB then make sure your connections

Comment: connection are properly added. ther is no issue of xib...

Comment: Your objects will already be added at those indexes so no need to write atIndex, just insert them. You don't need the .png after each image for UIImage imageNamed:. Also, your last image is probably named wrong. @"triangle" instead of @"traingle". Place a breakpoint and make sure all those objects are in the array before assigning them. If imgview is a property assign it with self. or _imgview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am looking your code this code is perfect but i think the problem is due to image not present in bundle if the images is present in bundle then delete all that images and adding once again trying this might be working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I Give you simple code that how to get image from ImageArray by relavent Button Click :

Suppose you have method of button is

```
-(void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
   images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage1.png"]];
   .
   .
   .

   UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[image objectAtIndex:sender.tag]; /// i Hope your each button has its own Tag.  

   /// here you get relavent image from button tapped by its tag;

  // put this image of you imageView.

   self.myImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake("AS YOU NEED")];
   self.myImgView.image = image;
   [self.mainBG addSubview:self.myImgView];
}
```

**Here make sure that your buttons have tag o to 20.**

**EDITE :**

Use it as *(just Give you example you need to update it at you code as it is)*

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender 
{
      NSString *images[] = 
    {
       @"image0.png",
       @"image1.png",
       .
       .
       .
    };

  self.myImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: images[sender.tag]];
}
```

Comment: @ iPatel no problem with array why are you tell hem to load array like your code @vasu array declare code is correct...

Comment: @JitendraDeore- then i thinks that there is no error in vasu's code :)

Comment: @iPatel  [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage1.png"]]; also trying this but still problem comes...

Comment: @Vasu- you are sure that each time when you clicked on different button then you got different "str" value ???

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom image view, if so then  [imgview setNeedsDisplay] will work, else it won't work. Please do check that as well.

Answer (score 0):

please try the following.

1) try `self.myImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cube.png"]` try using other images like @"rectangula prizm.png", @"tourus.png" ... See what happen if you set image directly. If the image is not displaying properly, then image is not inside bundle or image name is wrong.